# Error message while renewing developer license for developing windows store app

Tags: windows-8.1

I was working on a windows store application and got this error while trying to renew my developer license. I have tried a lot of things by running updates and restarting my computer. I am working in a VMware environment. I have not been able to renew my developer license. Any one has an idea on how I can fix this problem?

[image: Error message on screen]

Comment: ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE, "One or more errors were found in the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificate sent by the server".

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to happen with incorrect date/time or failing Internet connection:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/activation-errors